# Xamarin.Forms Prism Remove View from Navigation stack

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

Is it possible to remove a view from Navigation stack?

This is what I would like to achieve:

- Navigate to view 1
- Navigate to view 2
- Navigate to view 3

If in the view 3 I push the "go back" button,  I would like to go to View 1.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("yourApp:///NavigationPage/YourPage")
```

This is equivalent to

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new YourPage());
```

Note: I faced crash issue in `iOS`with navigating this way. I solved it by `Device.RuntimePlatform`

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.iOS:
        _navigationService.NavigateAsync("YourPage");
        break;
    case Device.Android:
        _navigationService.NavigateAsync("yourApp:///NavigationPage/YourPage");
        break;
    default:
        _navigationService.NavigateAsync("YourPage");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack.Last());
Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: Prism's INavigationService doesn't expose those methods

Comment: These are ContentView methods

Comment: Unfortunately I need call it in my ViewModel, using the NavigationService of Prism